# tensor product of formal power series

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A[[h]]$ be the formal power series algebra over $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$, here $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex number field. Is the 
canonical map $A[[h]] \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[[h]]} A[[h]] \to (A\otimes_\mathbb{C} A)[[h]]$  injective?
Thanks!

Comment: What canonical map?

Comment: Hi, egreg. The canonical map is sending \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i h^i\otimes  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_j h^j to the Cauchy product  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=i+j}a_i b_j h^n.

Comment: The codomain in your comment doesn't match the question's.

Comment: O.K. Let me write the map precisely.  It sends $ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i h^i\otimes \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}b_j h^j$ to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_i \otimes b_{n-i}) h^n.$

Comment: @egreq Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is that map well defined?

Comment: Yes,it is. One can check this by using the universal property of tensor product.